# htmlunit refering to element

Tags: java, htmlunit

I would like to programmatically issue a click on a web page and download the CSV file from the website. I'm trying to implement this logic with HtmlUnit library. The code that I'm trying to use:

```
HtmlPage historicalDataHtmlPage = webClient.getPage("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?p=GOOG");
                HtmlPage downloadHtmlPage = historicalDataHtmlPage.getAnchorByText("Download Data").click();
```

HtmlUnit seems to have a problem finding this particular element (not sure why - i tested this solution on other websites and it seems to find anchors by text).

Can you please advise how can I fix this error or how can I refer to the *Download Data* element in any other way?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the links mentioned by @pvg and modify your question as per the guidelines.

Having said that, have you tried using `getAnchors()` which returns a list  `List<HtmlAnchor>` and see what is the text you are getting inside the tag you want. Maybe there are other elements which do not match your text assumption of "Download Data".

---

Would have posted this as a comment but lack the reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the page starts with minimal content and adds you anchor later by doing some background requests.
Try to wait some seconds before you start searching for the anchor.
Also it is a good idea to use Page.asXML() to get an idea of the current status of the page (e.g. before and after the wait to see if something has changed.